# Gerador de cores

Tags: delphi

Desejo desenvolver um gerador de cores aleatórias mas que sejam claras, ou seja, que seja possível ler um texto com a cor preta sobre a cor gerada aleatoriamente.
Cores aleatórias consigo gerar por meio do seguinte código:
`RGB(RandomRange(0,255), RandomRange(0,255), RandomRange(0,255));`

A questão é: Como gerar **apenas cores claras**?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Um jeito bem simples é este:

```
RGB(RandomRange(150,255), RandomRange(150,255), RandomRange(150,255));
```

Basicamente você está fazendo com que a cor mínima seja 150, 150, 150.

Quanto mais alto começar o valor, mais claras as cores ficam. Se quisesse só cores escuras, seria o contrário:

```
RGB(RandomRange(0,150), RandomRange(0,150), RandomRange(0,150));
```

Em ambos os casos, ajuste o `150` em todas as entradas conforme sua preferência.

Se quiser cores vivas, compensa usar variáveis no lugar do 150, e criar uma fórmula que divida um número só entre o R G e B, mantendo a proporção mas permitindo "sobrecarregar" uma delas se a outra estiver escura.